# How to create a healthbar in Libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, nine-patch, scene2d

I have been wondering how I would go by making a health bar in libgdx/java. I am looking into a Shape Renderer thinking I can use a filled shape to create a health bar, though I am not sure on how to make an approach in that direction. On the other hand I have been looking into using scene2D and NinePatches to create a healthbar for the game. I have tried to use a NinePatch/Scene2D by looking up websites on google, though it seems when I add the code I always get an issue when I try to render it to my screen. So if anybody can help me create a functional health bar in libgdx using whatever method, I would be extremely thankful. Thank you.

I cannot post pictures yet, because I have not posted 10 posts. So here is the link http://gyazo.com/6650f3d820f31c99c3f8061ebed0bdec. Sorry

Comment: Your question isnt very well written. You tell us the methods you have tried but you don't show us the code. I suggest using Scene2d. Show us what you have tried in code.

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892694/libgdx-how-to-program-an-hp-bar

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with Scene2D and stages but here is how i would do a simple healthbar:

- Create a rectangle and fill this with a color or texture.
- When a player loses HP shorten that rectangle by the same percentage as the HP lost.
- Create a basic Orthographic camera with the height/width of the screen. I usually call this viewportCam.
- Below all the other draw logic you change the SpriteBatch too `spriteBatch(viewportCam.Combined)`
- Within this spritebatch you draw the healthbar.

> ```
> public void Draw()
> {
>     spriteBatch(normalCam.combined);
>     spriteBatch.begin();
>     //Normal draw logic.
>     spriteBatch.end();
>
>     spriteBatch(viewportCam.combined);
>     spriteBatch.begin();
>     //Draw UI elements last so the will be drawn on top of the rest.
>     spriteBatch.end();
> }
> ```

- If you draw a slightly larger rectangle behind the healthbar you have yourself a border.
- You can change color depending on how much percentage health is left.

**Edit**

Just came across this again and currently using another method. I a ninepatch from a 1 pixel wide red gradient. `health = new NinePatch(gradient, 0, 0, 0, 0)` this makes sure no artifacts occur while stretching it. From here I just calculate how long it needs to be and draw it.

```
width = currentHealth / totalHealth * totalBarWidth;
```

Now you can draw it anywhere you want.

```
health.draw(batch, 10, 10, width, gradient.getHeight);
```

If you want somekind of container for it you setup a ninepatch for it and draw it before the dynamic health in the background. So let's say the container is 2 bigger at top/bottom and 5 at left/right.

```
container = new NinePatch(containerRegion, 5, 5, 2, 2);
//Offset it by the dynamic bar, let's say the gradient is 4 high.
container.draw(batch, 5, 8, totalBarWidth + 10, 8);
health.draw(batch, 10, 10, width, 4);
```

I "hardcoded" the container 5 to the left and made it 10 longer so it fits horizontally. Vertically I lowered it by 2 and made it 8 high to fit the bar perfectly.

Comment: So you make 2 orthographic cameras, though one of them is going to be used for creation of the health bar? How would I go by making the rectangle shorten in size after being damaged, using a for loop to check if it is being attacked and simply -- from one health point? Thank you for the help, it seriously going to help me a lot.

Comment: I have tried this so far, I know I am definitely missing a part in the code. I also am having issues on where I should throw the methods into, i.e Render/create in my main. http://gyazo.com/fde6d8f36a027097576b848a491625d8

Comment: It also says I am getting an error in my constructor. Java Null Pointer, I believe it is something to do with my Vector2 ^ in the constructor though I think you need one to create a rectangle and set its position.

Comment: Yes your position vector is null when you attempt to use it. I'm unfamiliar with shape renderer too, but by the looks of it your game is static (as you do not have a moving camera. Then you do not have to make another camera for the "fixed" hud/ui. Just draw that rectangle somewhere and decrease it's width once something loses life. A basic HP bar should be very easy, maybe you should do another tutorial or two.

Comment: Just do position = new Vector2(int, int); to fill it. And no you do not "need" one for a rectangle, a rectangle just asks for a couple of int values. Maybe you should focus on drawing, moving and scaling something on screen. If you got those basics down a healthbar is simple.

Comment: Furthermore do not use ninepatch for basic immages. It is possible to make a hp bar with it but it is overkill imho. Afaik ninepatch uses a texture atlas so it knows how to cut up the texture and stretch all those different pieces in a correct way. Like i said, just altering the width of a rectangle would be enough for a HP bar.

Comment: I do have a moving Ortho camera that watches the players movement and follows him on the tiled map. How would I go by creating the filled shape and adding it to my rendering method without getting an error in my constructor in my recent most picture? Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: The null pointer error comes from the vector. You always need to assign something to a variable otherwise you get this error. So like i said position = new Vector2(int, int); would fix it. In my example i use normalCam as a movable camera amd viewportcam as a fixed. All i do with viewportCam is declare it and assign it the width and heigt of the screen. viewportCam = new OrthograpicCamera(width,height);. Then just draw UI elements within the begin/end of the spritebatch after you assigned the vieport cam to the spritebatch.

Comment: I called position = new Vector2(25,25), and added it in my constructor and am still getting an error. Should my constructor not take any parameters, though it is going to need a vector2 to get position.http://gyazo.com/d461c4dc8c79b1371837090299c6f5f2

Comment: That should do it. The error must come from somewhere else. Like i said, it is probably something basic. Try learn the basics first or do a simple tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it ,implement logic your self

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.Format;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;


public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
     int i=0;
    Texture texture,texture2;
    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        initTestObjects() ;
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();


        batch.draw(texture2,100,100,300,20);
    batch.draw(texture,100,100,i,20);
    if(i>300)
    {
        i=0;
    }
    i++;

        batch.end();
    }
    private void initTestObjects() {

        int width =1 ;
        int height = 1;
        Pixmap pixmap = createProceduralPixmap(width, height,0,1,0);
        Pixmap pixmap2 = createProceduralPixmap(width, height,1,0,0);

    texture = new Texture(pixmap);
    texture2 = new Texture(pixmap2);



        }



    private Pixmap createProceduralPixmap (int width, int height,int r,int g,int b) {
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Format.RGBA8888);

        pixmap.setColor(r, g, b, 1);
        pixmap.fill();

        return pixmap;
        }
}
```